# PHP simple messageboard - htmlentities not working right

Tags: php

I have built a very simple message board. The below PHP code is called from an HTML page with a form. The PHP code puts the form input contents at the bottom of the HTML page. That part works great But I can't get `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` working.

I am trying to prevent users from injecting HTML into the post. I will type something like `<h1> test </h1>` into the form and it will show up as the large h1 text on the page. I tried SO many variables, but every example code I could find wouldn't work.

Can someone please explain how I can use HTML character escaping? Do I use `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` to prevent posters from injecting html through the post form? If not, what is the alternative?

```
<?php

if ($_POST["p"]) {
$p = htmlentities($_POST["p"], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8");

}

if(isset($_POST['p'])) {
$data =  "<hr>" .  $_POST['p'] . "<br>" . "<br>" ."\r\n";
$ret = file_put_contents('index.html', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
if($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error writing this file');
}
else {
    header("Location: ./");
}
}
else {
die('no post data to process');
}
```

Comment: I don't you where you try to use `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()`. Please post your code where you actually implement them so we can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Show us where you echo the html. You should escape data when printing out the html.

Comment: **Show your code**. Without it we cannot help you.

Comment: Edit your question and add it there, please